# calculating the density of a set

Tags: mysql, math

(I wish my mathematical vocabulary was more developed)

I have a website. On that website is a video. As a user watches the video, a bit of javascript stores how far they have gotten so far in the video. When they stop watching the video, that number of seconds is stored. There's no pattern to when the js will do this, unfortunately.

So if one person is watching the video, we might see this set:

```
3
6
8
10
12
16
```

And another person might get bored immediately:

```
1
3
```

This data is all stored in the same place, anonymously. So the sorted table with all this info would look like this:

```
1
3
3
6
8
10
12
16
```

Finally, the amount of times the video is started at all is stored. In this case it would be `2`.

**So.** How do I get the average 'high-time' (the farthest reached point in the video) for all of the times the video was played?

I know that if we had a value for every second:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
14
15
16

1
2
3
```

Then we could count up the values and divide by the number of plays:

```
(19) / 2 = 9.5
```

Or if the data was otherwise uniform, say in increments of 5, then we could count that up and multiply it by 5 (in the example, we would have some loss of precision, but that's ok):

```
5
10
15

5

(4) * 5 / 2 = 10
```

So it seems like I have a general function which would work:

```
count * 1/d = avg
```

where `d` is the density of the numbers (in the example above with 5 second increments, `1/5`).

**Is there a way to derive the density, `d`, from a set of effectively random numbers?**

Comment: Why store the incremental values? Don't you know if a person watched 30 seconds of a video, they also watched 1, 5, 10 seconds of it as well? If all the numbers are stored in the same list, you'll have the additional pain of finding out which numbers are maximums, and which are just another number in some other sequence.

Comment: Right - unfortunately, I have no way of changing the way the numbers are stored.

Comment: To make things a bit more clear - I actually have hundreds of millions of these numbers which are stored in a huge table. There are performance and backwards compatibility reasons for those numbers being 'anonymous', and my not being able to rely on them being uniform.

Comment: If there are two views with results `1, 2, 3`, how do you know: were the views `1` and `2, 3` or `2` and `1, 3`?

Comment: @Quassnoi - I think you may have proved that it's impossible. I hope not. =)

Comment: The same data `1 3 3 6 8 10 12 16` could also come from 2 persons : `1 3 10 16` and `3 6 8 12`. You need to know something about the increments. Can we assume that it always is around 5?

Comment: Let's say that it's always 5 second increments, EXCEPT for when they stop the video. So you would have `5, 10, 15, 18` and `5, 10, 11`. Does that make it possible?

Comment: If the data is output uniformly along an interval, this is easy. First, sort the numbers. Then, start picking from the highest ones. For each highest number, remove all subsequent lower numbers in the interval. Then, once you finish with your current highest number, move to the next highest number, and remove all the lower numbers along the interval. Your resulting numbers will be the highest numbers that are left.

Comment: @Brian Stiner: Yes, if the intervals are long enough that their boundaries are obvious, then the problem can be solved by hand. I think colinmarc wants something more robust and automated.

Comment: If it's always 5 second increments except when they stop, then the problem is trivial. Are you sure you want to restrict it that much?

Comment: @Beta - I would rather not rely on the points being uniform.

Comment: @Beta My approach with uniform intervals can be automated. What portion did I not explain clear enough to show how it could be automated and I will try and expand on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @brian-stiner is on the right track in one of his comments.

Start with something like:

```
1
3
3
6
8
10
12
16
```

Turn that into numbers and counts.

```
1, 1
3, 2
6, 1
8, 1
10, 1
12, 1
16, 1
```

And then reading from the end down, find all of the points that happened more often than any remaining ones.

```
3, 2
16, 1
```

Take differences in counts.

```
3, 1
16, 1
```

And you have an estimate of stopping places.

This will **not** be an unbiased estimate.  But if the JavaScript is independently inconsistent and the number of people is large, the biases should be fairly small.

It won't be right, but it will be close enough for government work.

Comment: could you elaborate on that second step?

Comment: @colinmarc: All you do there is turn a list with repeated elements into a list of distinct elements and their frequency counts.

Comment: oops. I meant the third step.

Comment: @colinmarc: Start from the end of the list, keep track of the highest frequency count seen, whenever I encounter a higher one emit the number, the jump in frequency count, and change the highest frequency count seen.  Reverse the emitted list and you have it.

Comment: I like your idea of throwing away (likely) intermediate values.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just keep the last time that has been provided, and average across those? If you either throw away, or only pay attention to, the last number, it seems like you could just average over these.

You might also want to check out the term [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) as the raw average of this might not be the most useful measurement. If you have the standard deviation as well, it could help you realize that you have an average of 7, but it is composed of mostly 1's and 15's.

If you HAVE to have all the data, like you suggested, I will try and think about this a little bit more. I'm not totally certain how you can associate a value with all the previous values that came with it. Do you ALWAYS know the sequence by which numbers are output? If so, I think I know of a way you could derive the 'last' one, which might be slightly computationally expensive.

If you only have a sequence of integers, I think you may be able to increase each value (exponentially?) to 'compensate' for the fact that a later value 'contains' earlier values. I'm still working through this idea, but maybe it will give someone else a seed. What if you average over the sum of these, and then take the [base2 logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) of this average? Does that provide any kind of useful metric? That should 'weight' the later values to the point where they compensate for the sum of earlier values. I think.

In python-esk:

```
sum = 0
numberOf = 0  
for node in nodes:
   sum = sum + node.value ^ 2
   numberOf = numberOf + 1
weightedAverage = log(sum/numberOf, 2) 
print weightedAverage
print "Thanks Brian"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Obviously I could do this any number of better ways - the point is more that I have this data already, can I get the average high time from it?

Comment: Can you tell me, with certainty, the sequence of numbers which are output for any 'final' number?

Comment: No. The js could fire and record the number of seconds so far at any point.

Comment: OK. I think I came up with a weighting system which can compensate for this.

Comment: Can you concretely state that the following entries will be within some interval? If you can make this interval as small as possible, I believe you should be able to see an exponential decay along this interval as time points drop off.

Comment: like the length of the video?

Comment: Well, that would be a concrete guarantee, but not super useful. If you could say that most of the videos drop these numbers at least every n seconds, and the video is n*m (with m > say 10), you could infer along a step size of n, how many videos were cancelled. This is an abstraction of the case where the video drops a number every 1 (my comment on the question.) If you can say that you think the videos will drop every n seconds, you can use that approach along an interval.

Comment: Well, also this would be most useful if it was along the interval, and only once within the interval... I still think this approach could provide some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total time watched for each user, you'll have parse the list smallest to largest. If you have 4 views, you'll go through your list until you find that you no longer have 4 identical numbers, the last number where you had 4 identical numbers is the maximum of the first view. Then you'll look for when the 3 identical numbers stop, and so on. For example:

4 views data:
1111222233334445566778

4 views side by side:

1  1  1  1 
2  2  2  2 
3  3  3  3 <- first view max is 3 seconds
4  4     4 <- second view max is 4 seconds
5        5 
6        6
7        7 <- third view max is 7 seconds
8          <- fourth view max is 8 seconds

**EDIT-** Oh, I just noticed that they are not uniform. In that case, the moving average would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming increments are always around 5, some missing, some a bit longer or shorter. Then it won't be easy (possible?) to do this exactly. My suggestion: compute something like a 'moving count'. Similar to [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

So, for second 7: count how many numbers are 5,6,7,8 or 9 and divide by 5. That will give you a pretty good guess of how many people watched the 7th second. Do the same for second 10. The difference would be close to the number of the people who left between second 7 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

The number of values roughly corresponds to the number of time periods in which your javascript sends the values (minus 1/2 if the video stop is accompanied with a obligatory time posting, since its moment is random within the interval).

If all clients have similar intervals and you know them, you may just use:

```
SELECT  (COUNT(*) - 0.5) * 5.0 / (SELECT counter FROM countertable)
FROM    ticktable
```

`5.0` is the interval between the posts here.

Note that it does not even look at the values: you could as well just store "ticks".

Comment: @colinmarc: imagine your ticks go every 5 seconds and you have 4 ticks. The final tick is the video stop which can be anywhere from 15 to 20 seconds, distributed uniformly (it may be `4, 9, 13, 16` or `6, 11, 14, 19`). We can assume that the average view time for `4` ticks is `17.5` seconds which is `(4 - 0.5) * 5.0`

Answer (score -1):

For the max time, you could use `MAX()` on your field. Perhaps something like...

`SELECT MAX(play_time) AS maxTime FROM video`

Which would give you the longest time someone has played the video for.

If you want other things, like `AVG()` then you'll need more complex queries, for collecting on a per-user basis etc etc.

MySQL also contains a Standard Deviation function called `STDDEV()` and `STD()` which could help you too.

Comment: all the data for all the users is in the same place. So `MAX()` would just return one value.

Comment: Then I'd say that your table is poorly constructed.

Comment: This is true! But there is a limitation to what is possible with data sets.